# How to diagnose random wifi outages

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

At my home network I'm experiencing random WiFi outages. My notebook is connected to WiFi and then all network traffic stops. The WiFi connection is fine, I have 90% signal strength (-47 dBi on average, measured using inSSIDer). The router is TP Link tl-wr741nd running in N-mode.

To diagnose this problem I was running NetTK to find the issue. The network has following layout:
[image: home network layout]

Windows machine and phone are on WiFi and Xubuntu machine was connected using cable.

During the outage I was unable to ping from the Windows or phone to the router I got destination unreachable and then timeout. During the same outage, the Xubuntu machine happily pinged the router, ISP's gateway and google DNS.

Given this info I was able to isolate the problem at the router. It's not the radio itself, as the signal did not drop. The ether is a bit crowded here:
[image: network intensity graph]

But I don't think, the problem is due to interference, first the signal quality is still same, and the router is only 3 meters away, in clear view.

The only way to resolve the outage is to disconnect from the WiFi and connect again. Neither phone nor notebook reconnects automatically (well, in 15 minutes), only when I disconnect manually and connect again then I'm online immediately.

I cannot change anything in the router settings, as I'm locked out of it by my ISP. Their technician told me, that they can provide me with more powerful router with 10W radio. So I don't really have any hopes they will be able to diagnose it.

Lately the same problem started on other devices in my network as well. Which suggests it's not OS network card problem, but router problem. The only common factor which I noticed is, that the problem starts when I watch Youtube videos. On the other hand, my ISP gives me 40Mbpbs, which is not that so much.

**Do you have any idea what can cause this problem? Can getting more powerful router solve my problem?** I have suspicion that this router is under-powered, and the processor cannot handle the traffic. In that case model with more powerful CPU should improve my situation.

**UPDATE**

Here is the output of `route print` during outage:

```
route print

===========================================================================
Interface List
  5...ac 7b a1 a4 bd d0 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  4...ac 7b a1 a4 bd cf ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260
  3...d8 50 e6 97 2b cc ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
  8...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.103     30
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.103    286
    192.168.0.103  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.103    286
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.103    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.103    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.103    286
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  8    306 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  8    306 2001::/32                On-link
  8    306 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:3841:1f01:b297:2753/128
                                    On-link
  4    286 fe80::/64                On-link
  8    306 fe80::/64                On-link
  8    306 fe80::3841:1f01:b297:2753/128
                                    On-link
  4    286 fe80::516a:3053:996e:3b1c/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  8    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  4    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

**UPDATE 2**
I've done some more testing and I start to suspect it's the routers fault. When my machine is not connected, everything is fine, but as soon as I connect everything starts to fail. The main difference in my NTB is, that it supports 802.11n, when I force the card to use 802.11g the problems are mostly gone. So I would guess the router does not support 802.11n as well as it advertises.

Comment: Please try the following two commands on your Win laptop during disconnection: "ifconfig" and "route print". That gives us some info on the network status. Did you try Windows Networking Troubleshooter during outage?

Comment: ifconfig doesn't show any change, so it doesn't seem it's a DHCP problem. I will try the route print, but I doubt it will get further than the ping.